# Hi I am trying to add the material ui Iconbutton with input ref to upload the image its not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

[click to  check the image here of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyOpX.png) HiI am trying to add the material UI button to upload the image it's not working below is the code snippet and reference to sandbox I am trying to work like in the image but not working
I had gone to the reference of reacting uploading and other methods how could I add the remove button in the below functionality code

code sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-hoover-3kjfi?file=/src/App.js

```
    [import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import AvatarEditor from "react-avatar-editor";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import MuiThemeProvider from "@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import {
  Box,
  Typography,
  Button,
  IconButton,
  Grid,
  Divider,
} from "@material-ui/core";
// import ImageUploading from "react-images-uploading";

export default function Images() {
  const \[state, setState\] = useState({
    cropperOpen: false,
    img: null,
    zoom: 2,
    rotate: 0,
    croppedImg: "",
  });


  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  function handleZoomSlider(event, value) {
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, zoom: value }));
  }

 function handleFileChange (e) {
    const createObjectURL =
      (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL ||
      window.createObjectURL;

    const file = e.target.files\[0\];
    // console.log(file);
    const image_url = createObjectURL(file);
    setState({
      tmpPhotoURL: image_url,
      file: file,
    });
  };

//   function handleFileChange(e) {
//     window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
//     let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files\[0\]);

//     inputRef.current.value = "";
//     setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, img: url, cropperOpen: true }));
//   }

  function handleCancel() {
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, cropperOpen: false }));
  }



  function handleSave(e) {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      const canvasScaled = editorRef.current.getImageScaledToCanvas();
      const croppedImg = canvasScaled.toDataURL();

      setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, cropperOpen: false, croppedImg }));
    }
  }

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      
      
          <div style={{ height: 100, width: 120 }}>
            <Avatar src={state.croppedImg} size={100} />

          
                <Button
                  //   label="Upload an Image"
                  //   labelPosition="before"
                  //   containerElement="label"
                  size="medium"
                  variant="contained"
                
                  color="secondary"
                 
                  ref={inputRef}
                  type="file"
                  accept="image/*"
                  onChange={handleFileChange}
                >
                    
                  Upload an Image
                </Button>][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<input type="file"/>` for uploading any kind of file. If you want to look like the material button, use custom css.

https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#upload-button  - here you have an example for **Upload** button

Comment: i had tried the custom css using material ui for the above code format its not working. import {

  Button,
 
} from "@material-ui/core";

Comment: check the link I provided

Comment: I tried IconButton  but not working with input ref can u once try the design in code sandbox and share it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131925/cropping-functionalityreact-easy-crop-is-not-working-when-i-try-to-upload-an-i

Answer (score 0):

```
        [import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import AvatarEditor from "react-avatar-editor";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import MuiThemeProvider from "@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import {
  Box,
  Typography,
  Button,
  IconButton,
  Grid,
  Divider,
} from "@material-ui/core";
// import ImageUploading from "react-images-uploading";

export default function Images() {
  const \[state, setState\] = useState({
    cropperOpen: false,
    img: null,
    zoom: 2,
    rotate: 0,
    croppedImg: "",
  });


  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  function handleZoomSlider(event, value) {
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, zoom: value }));
  }

 function handleFileChange (e) {
    const createObjectURL =
      (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL ||
      window.createObjectURL;

    const file = e.target.files\[0\];
    // console.log(file);
    const image_url = createObjectURL(file);
    setState({
      tmpPhotoURL: image_url,
      file: file,
    });
  };

//   function handleFileChange(e) {
//     window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
//     let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files\[0\]);

//     inputRef.current.value = "";
//     setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, img: url, cropperOpen: true }));
//   }

  function handleCancel() {
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, cropperOpen: false }));
  }



  function handleSave(e) {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      const canvasScaled = editorRef.current.getImageScaledToCanvas();
      const croppedImg = canvasScaled.toDataURL();

      setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, cropperOpen: false, croppedImg }));
    }
  }

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      
      
          <div style={{ height: 100, width: 120 }}>
            <Avatar src={state.croppedImg} size={100} />

          
                <Button
                  //   label="Upload an Image"
                  //   labelPosition="before"
                  //   containerElement="label"
                  size="medium"
                  variant="contained"
                
                  color="secondary"
                 
                  ref={inputRef}
                  type="file"
                  accept="image/*"
                  onChange={handleFileChange}
                >
                    
                  Upload an Image
                </Button>][1]
```

anyone could help the image design in codesandbox